# Two-state system problem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation

Given a 2-state system with (complete set) orthonormal eigenstates $u_1, u_2$ with eigenvalues $E_1, E_2$ respectively, where $E_2>E_1$, and there exists a linear operator $\hat{L}$ with eigenvalues $\pm1$,

1. would the normalized eigenfunctions (in terms of the given eigenstates) just be $$u_1\over \sqrt{\int u_1^*u_1}$$ ? Since I am not given an argument/coordinate system for the eigenstates, perhaps I should first project them into one? But I don't have any info on the nature of the quantum system...
2. A second question asks for the expectation values of the energy in the respective states. But isn't that just $E_1$ and $E_2$ respectively??

Grateful for any enlightenment.

Comment: And what does that linear operator have to do with anything?

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes. However, you say that $u$ are orthonormal which contains normalization

2) Yes. I presume, it some sort of a homework. Sometimes it is useful to check/show fact like this in details.

And what $\hat{L}$ have to do with the question?

Comment: Thanks, Misha. Like I said in my comment to the problem, I really don't see the relevance of the linear operator... HenceI was confused... BTW, what sort of detail could I show? Isn't this all from definition?

Comment: Found the catch to the linear operator bit, there is apparently another bit of the question later on that has to do with it. But I still don't know how to "calulate" the expected energy for each of the states, since it seems to follow from definition...!

Comment: @justcurious It is not definition. State with energy usually means eigenfunction of Hamiltonian. Expectation value of the operator definition is a bit different. To go from one to another you still need one pretty obvious line.
\\
  You may reformulate the question right here. I can add new details in my answer. It is Ok.

Comment: Thanks again, Misha. :) So $\langle E \rangle = \langle H \rangle$? Then we have to do $\int u_1^*Hu_1$ where $H$ is the Hamiltonian? Unfortunately, the question only has the information I have given in the question above...

Comment: Also, what argument would I be integrating with rescet to (since it is not given in the question)?

Comment: @justcurious . Once again. For the first state $\langle H\rangle = \int u_1^* H u_1 $ by definition. You may show that it is equal to $E_1$. Do you have problems with this?

Comment: $\int u_1^*Hu_1 = \int E_1 u^*u = E_1$, right?